# Why does an additional `*` gets appended to the output in the following bash command?

Tags: bash, shell, command, echo, tr

When I run the command `$ echo "Hello, World!" | tr -c 'aeiou' '*'`, the terminal returns `*e**o***o*****`. There are only 4 characters after the last vowel `o`, so `tr` should replace each of them with a `*` to return `*e**o***o****`, but it is adding one more `*` to the output string which seems illogical to me.

I also tried `$ echo "o!" | tr -c 'aeiou' '*'`, but still it is returning `o**` instead of `o*`.

Can anyone please help me understand the reason?

Comment: There is an invisible linefeed at the end, that is translated too. Try `echo -n ...`  or better use `printf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo 'o!'` outputs three characters: `o`, `!` and a Line Feed.

```
$ echo 'o!' | od -t c
0000000   o   !  \n
0000003
```

`printf 'o!'` only outputs the first two.

```
$ printf 'o!' | od -t c
0000000   o   !
0000002
```

Alternatively, you could preserve the Line Feed using `tr -c 'aeiou\n' '*'` (at least on my system).

Comment: Thanks man. I was getting intuition about the "line feed" playing some role here, but was unable to crack it, but now I ran `echo "Hello, World!" | xclip -selection c` and learnt the behaviour of echo. thanks